# EF6 does not lazy load navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm having an issue with EF6 lazy loading. I've searched StackOverflow, but the other questions I've found doesn't fit my case.

I'm using the `virtual` keyword and my classes are `public`. `LazyLoadingEnabled` and `ProxyCreationEnabled` are both set to `true`.

When I load a `course` object from the db, `presentationId` is set to the correct `id` and `presentation` is `null` which is correct, because it hasn't been loaded yet.

When I pass the `presentation` property to the `PresentationsController.ToDto()` method it should be lazy loaded, but I get a `null reference` exception inside the method because it's still `null`.

I know that the relationships are working because when I force load the `presentation` property of a `course` in the `Watch window` with a break point at the `public static CourseDto ToDto(Course item, DnbContext db)` method it gets loaded. See images:

As you can see `item.presentation` is `null`:

[image]

When I manually evaluate `db.courses.Find(257).presentation` which is referencing the same presentation as the `item` object does, they're both loaded:

[image]

Here are my POCOs:

```
public abstract class BaseModel : ISoftDelete {
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Course : BaseModel {
    [Required]
    public int presentationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Presentation presentation { get; set; }
}
```

My Web API controller methods:

```
// GET api/Courses/5
public CourseDto GetCourse(int id) {
    var item = db.courses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
    return ToDto(item, db);
}

public static CourseDto ToDto(Course item, DnbContext db) {
    var dto = new CourseDto();

    if (item.presentationId > 0) dto.presentation = PresentationsController.ToDto(item.presentation, db);

    return dto;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entities must have explicitly declared public constructors if you want to use lazy loading via dynamic proxies. (If you have other with parameters)

```
public abstract class BaseModel : ISoftDelete {
    public BaseModel() { }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Course : BaseModel {
    public Course() { }
    [Required]
    public int presentationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Presentation presentation { get; set; }
}
```