# Navigation properties not loading in Lazy Load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, poco

I've create these two classes (POCO)...

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Neighborhood { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

... then I mapping...

```
public class AddressMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        ToTable("Address");

        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        ...
        ...

        HasRequired(p => p.City)
            .WithMany(p => p.Addresses)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CityId);
    }
}

public class CityMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    public CityMap()
    {
        ToTable("City");

        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        ...
        ...

        HasMany(p => p.Addresses)
            .WithRequired(p => p.City)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CityId);
    }
}
```

Then I create a class with two methods:

- `FindCityById` which returns a City and their respective addresses... *`Context.Cities.Find(key)`* and
- `GetAllAddresses` (just for test purposes) *`Context.Addresses.ToList()`*

When I use `FindCityById`... the addresses related are loaded!

When I use `GetAllAddresses`, the `CityId` has value but City is always null.

`ProxyCreationEnabled` and `LazyLoadingEnabled` are "true".

Why the City is not loading when I'm in Address class?

Comment: What do you mean that it is not loaded, since it's lazy loading, it will be loaded when you are trying to access the address in the collection.

Comment: I found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194266/ef6-does-not-lazy-load-navigation-property?rq=1
The EF needs a explicit declaration of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use **WithRequiredPrincipal** or **WithRequiredDependent** after the **HasRequired** method.

Have a look at [Entity Framework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620.aspx)

In most cases the Entity Framework can infer which type is the dependent and which is the principal in a relationship. However, when both ends of the relationship are required or both sides are optional the Entity Framework cannot identify the dependent and principal. When both ends of the relationship are required, use WithRequiredPrincipal or WithRequiredDependent after the HasRequired method.